# jOOQ fetch into DTO with Set of joined records

Tags: java, jooq

I am working with jOOQ. I want to perform a select and joins to fetch into a DTO. My DTO has an instance of `Table1Record`, `Table2Record`, a set of `Table3Record`s, and one `Table4Record`.

```
public class Dto {
  private Table1Record table1;
  private Table2Record table2;
  private Set<Table1Record> subTable1s;
  private Table4Record table4;

  // All arg constructor and getters/setters.
}
```

I start my query with:

```
dsl
    .select()
    .from(TABLE_1)
    .leftJoin(TABLE_2).on(TABLE_2.TABLE_1_ID.eq(TABLE_1.ID)
```

I know that I need to do something like `.fetch(record ->` , and then use `record.into(TABLE_1)`, etc, but I don't know how to do it for the set of `Table1Records`s. Assume that there is a join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the [`MULTISET` operator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) to nest your data directly in SQL? It's all type safe and supported in a variety of RDBMS:

```java
List<Dto> list =
dsl.select(
        TABLE_1,
        TABLE_2,
        multiset(
            select(TABLE_3)
            .from(TABLE_3)
            .where(TABLE_3.TABLE_1_ID.eq(TABLE_1.ID)
        ).convertFrom(r -> r.collect(Records.intoSet())),
        TABLE_4
    )
   .from(TABLE_1)
   .leftJoin(TABLE_2).on(TABLE_2.TABLE_1_ID.eq(TABLE_1.ID))
   .leftJoin(TABLE_2).on(TABLE_2.TABLE_1_ID.eq(TABLE_1.ID))
   .where(...)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Dto::new));
```

This makes use of the following features:

- [`MULTISET` value constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/)
- [Ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) (`convertFrom(..)` converts from a `List<R>` to a `Set<R>`)
- [Projecting `Table` as `SelectField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/select-clause-table/) (since you want the `TableNRecord` type in your Dto anyway. If not, just use ad-hoc conversion again)

Of course, you can always flatten (denormalise) your results using joins and then [collect them again into groups](https://blog.jooq.org/use-resultquery-collect-to-implement-powerful-mappings/), but that's a lot of manual work every time you do this.

Comment: I made a typo in my original question. Changing now.

Comment: @Oliver: It doesn't really change anything though, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Multiset was the way to go.